# Reactjs assigned variable inside setState is undefined but method returns data correctly

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-component, react-state-management

Inside a method in component I have this:

```
  this.setState({
      projectResponse: {},
      project: {},
      isLoading: true
    });
    var homeService = new HomeService();


    this.setState({
      isLoading:false,
      projectResponse: homeService.getProjectStatusById(this.props.id)
    });
```

When I try to use `this.state.projectResponse.doSomething` it tells me that projectResponse is undefined. But if I try to print the content using `homeService.getProjectStatusById(this.props.id).doSomething` it prints it correctly.
The method getProjectStatusById simply returns an array, so I've tried printing on console its length. With first method the response is undefined, with the second method it prints the length correctly.

Comment: When do you call `this.state.projectResponse.doSomething`? `setState` is not guaranteed to run synchronously, so there is usually a delay between calling `setState` and the state actually updating.

Comment: How can one rewrite the logic to solve this?

Comment: Well, as I said, it depends on where you retrieve the state. If it is in `render`, it should be called with already updated state. Otherwise, you can pass a callback to `setState` which is invoked when the state is actually updated - see the [React docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate).